# Why first box cannot be drawn after set the container?

Tags: css

```css
.container1{ width:1100px; height:100%; clear:both; margin:auto;}

.Review{ border:1px solid #000; list-style-type:none;
         padding:20px 30px 20px 50px;}

.Comments{ list-style-type:none; text-align:justify;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
           font-size:18px; padding-top:10px;}

.Review1{ border:1px solid #000; list-style-type:none;
          padding:20px 30px 20px 50px;}
```

I want to ask after set the container the 1st box cannot be drawn?
Because my .Review doesn't draw a box...... but .Review1 done it!!
I want 2 boxes inside the container, is that possible?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too, please. Nothing wrong at first sight here; need more context.

Comment: Two box means.? Two border.?

Comment: <div class="container1">
<div class="Review">     
<ul class="Comments"></ul></div> (end review) 
<div class="Review1">
<ul class="Comments"></ul></div> (end review1)              
  <div class="Actions">
  <button type="submit" name="post">Post a Rating</button>
  </div>
  
</div>

Comment: here attach with html...... two boxes means two border inside the container like one refers to review, another refers to review1.....